# Is there a way to structure an if statement so that it can identify if an XPATH exists in python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, findelement

I am currently playing around with Selenium trying to learn it by doing and have encountered this issue; occasionally a button on the website appears with a different XPATH, so I wanted to try and create a workaround. This is what I am trying to use:

```
if bool(wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="basketPageApp"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/a')) == TRUE:
    button = wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="basketPageApp"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/a')
else:
    button = wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="guestCheckout"]/div/div/div[2]/section/div[2]/div[1]/div')
```

I'm sure I can't use an if statement in this manner but I hope this gets the idea of what I am trying to achieve across.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium will throw an exception in case `find_element` method could not find element matching the passed locator.
It will not return you a Boolean `True` or `False`.
What can you do here is to use `find_elements_by_xpath` instead of `find_element_by_xpath` since `find_elements_by_xpath` will return you a list of found matches. So, in case there was a match you will get a non-empty list interpreted by Python as a Boolean `True` while in case of no match found it will return an empty list interpreted by Python as a Boolean `False`. Also, this will never throw exception.
So your code could be something like:

```py
if wd.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="basketPageApp"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/a'):
    button = wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="basketPageApp"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/a')
else:
    button = wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="guestCheckout"]/div/div/div[2]/section/div[2]/div[1]/div')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `try and except`

```py
try:
    button = wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="basketPageApp"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/a')
except:
    button = wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="guestCheckout"]/div/div/div[2]/section/div[2]/div[1]/div')
```